# compare a string from a table and compare each keyword from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

table 1 contains a list of sentences:

```
Sentence
----------------------------------------------------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
```

and table 2 contains a list of keywords and weights:
tblKeyword

```
Keyword                                   Weight
----------------------------------------------------------------
dolor sit                                  1
elit                                       3
foobar                                     10
```

For each sentence in table 1, I would like to get a sum of Weight of all keywords within table 2 that could be found in the sentence from table 1.  How can I do this in SQL without using cursor?

expected result:

```
 Result
 ------
 4   (sum of weight for sentence 1)
 6   (sum of weight for sentence 2)
 ...
```

Comment: What is the expected result. Did you try anything

Comment: Hi, i just would like to get a sum of weight of how many keywords could be found within each sentence of table 1.

Comment: Since weight can be relative, can you explain? SOUNDEX, DIFFERENCE among others can be used with LIKE and thesaurus, dictionary, and so on to compare. Try to do something first,or read MSDN and ask a related question. We are not a google search after all.

Comment: Actually the "weight" here means only a mark to represent how much the keyword should be valued, it does not need to be relative but an arbitrary magnitude to which i valued the keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT
  S.sentence
  , SUM(K.weight) AS total_weight
FROM Sentence S
JOIN Keyword K
  ON CHARINDEX(K.keyword, S.sentence) > 0
GROUP BY S.sentence
;
```

(Sorry: No access to a SQL Server instance to verify. Tried with MySQL and replaced `INSTR` with `CHARINDEX`.)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Yes thanks I think your answer should work, I just modified a little bit to run on SQL Server 2014: changing CHARINDEX to CHARINDEX(K.keyword, S.sentence)

Comment: @nikademus: Thanks for the hint. Sorry for the oversight. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I not recommend cursor, but as per your requirment, the only option I found is cursor. Please check this :

```
declare @table1 table ( sentences varchar(1000))
declare @table2 table ( keyword varchar(1000) , weight int)

insert into @table1 values 
( 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua')
,('Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur' )


insert into @table2 values 
('dolor sit' , 1),('elit' , 3),('foobar' , 10)

/*Declare temp variable*/
declare @tab TABLE ( sentSeqno int,  result int) --to get final result create temporary table and insert temp data

declare @keyword varchar(1000), @weight int , @Recordno int = 0 , @sentences varchar(1000);

/*first cursor for table 1 for iteration of each row*/
DECLARE @cursorouter CURSOR ; 
SET @cursorouter = CURSOR FOR  select * from @table1
OPEN @cursorouter
FETCH NEXT FROM @cursorouter INTO @sentences  --FILL IN CURSOR TO LOOP THROUGH
/* loop first cursor while having data*/
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN

       /*Insert into temp data*/ 
       Set @Recordno = @Recordno + 1    insert into @tab values(@Recordno, 0)

       /*Second cursor for table 2 to for iteration of each row*/
       DECLARE @cursorInner CURSOR ; 
        SET @cursorInner = CURSOR FOR 

        select * from @table2 
        OPEN @cursorInner
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM @cursorInner INTO @keyword , @weight --FILL IN CURSOR TO LOOP THROUGH

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
            BEGIN
                    /*to find the keyword in a sentence, we start loop and whenever found the keyword, we store its weightage*/
                    Declare @pos int =0
                    Declare @oldpos int = 0 

                    select @pos= patindex('%' + @keyword +'%' , @sentences) 
                    /*While loop for each keyword found in sentence, we store the weightage into temp table*/
                    while @pos > 0 and @oldpos <> @pos
                     begin
                        /*update temp data to store result*/ 
                       update @tab set result = result+ @weight where sentSeqno = @Recordno
                       Select @oldpos = @pos
                       select @pos=patindex(@sentences,Substring(@keyword,@pos + 1,len(@keyword))) + @pos
                    end

            FETCH NEXT
            FROM @cursorInner INTO @keyword , @weight;
        END
        CLOSE @cursorInner;
        DEALLOCATE @cursorInner;

    FETCH NEXT
        FROM @cursorouter INTO @sentences;
    END
    CLOSE @cursorouter;
    DEALLOCATE @cursorouter;

select * from @tab
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion.  I did something similar as well but i found the performance is really slow when I have much more sentences (something about 10000 lines).  My config. is SQL Server 2014 with XEON  E3 1220 v3.  It takes really long to run.